# The method OnTouchEvent not respond in a ScrollView

Tags: android

I've already read more articles about this, but I haven't found any solution, sorry!

I have a .xml file with a scrollView:

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</ScrollView>
```

And I have the next code:

```
public class Example extends Activity{

//I have more code

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
int x = (int) event.getX();
int y = (int) event.getY();

switch(event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

    break;
}   
return true;
}
}
```

If I have the scrollView the method is never executed, but if I quit the scrollView the method works perfectly. How I can make the method work with the scrollView?
THANKS for your attention and your help.